# HTML Form to SQL Database

Tags: html, mysql, sql-server

I have an HTML form that I want to connect to a SQL Database into a table. I have little to no experience with SQL as this is my first time actually using it. I've learned some basic commands via CodeAchedemy but other than that, I have no clue what I'm doing.

I've created a table on my database with columns and now I'm trying to find a way where I can send the information gathered from the form to the table. I do not know how to link the database up or anything. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the basic form I have without additional things:

```
<form action="" method="">

<label>First Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Andrew...">

<label>Last Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Smith...">

<label>First Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="cus-firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John...">

<label>Last Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="cus-lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Williams...">

<label>Email <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="cus-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="John@paradime.com">

<input type="checkbox" name="design" value="design">
<p>The Original</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="design" value="design">
<p>Something Else</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="Small">
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="Medium">
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="Large">
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="X-Large">
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="XX-Large">

<label>Text</label><br>
 <select name="quantity" class="form-control">
 <option disabled="" selected="">- Quantity -</option>
 <option value="one"> 1 </option>
 <option value="two"> 2 </option>
 <option value="three"> 3 </option>
 <option value="four"> 4 </option>
 <option value="five"> 5 </option>
 <option value="six"> 6 </option>
 <option value="seven"> 7 </option>
 <option value="eight"> 8 </option>
 <option value="nine"> 9 </option>
 <option value="ten"> 10 </option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" name="price">

<label>Colour</label><br>
 <select name="colour" class="form-control">
    <option disabled="" selected="">- Colour -</option>
    <option value="ANTIQ-CHERRY-RED"> ANTIQ CHERRY RED </option>
    <option value="ANTIQUE-SAPPHIRE"> ANTIQUE SAPPHIRE </option>
 </select>                                                

<input type='button' name='finish' value='Finish'/>

</form>
```

Comment: You should learn server side scripting like php to do this for you.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar, okay. So CodeAcademy should help?

Comment: You'll need some means of connecting to the database which by itself HTML can't do. What front end tools do you have at your disposal? ASP.NET? Node?

Comment: Yes, it will :)

Comment: HTML is just a User Interface.

Comment: @Xedni, I have no idea to be quite honest with you. I'm using x10hosting.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar okay!

Comment: Try to use Visual Studio or PHP etc.

Comment: @reds, so as saravananSampathkumar mentioned, PHP should do the work?

Comment: Then the answer is going to be unfortunately pretty vague. No disrespect but you're several steps away from being able to do what you're describing. I'd look up some tutorials on PHP, or (as I'm partial to) ASP.Net. You'll need to get comfortable writing server side code and connect HTML inputs to that code. Fortunately, there are many resources available. CodeAcademy is good. There are also tons of tutorials and books you can find online.

Comment: There's a lot lot of server side application could do this.

Comment: @Xedni, oh man..okay then! I get to learning it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @reds, okay. I think as Xedni mentioned, I'll try to see if I can learn some code that could do this. If I can't learn it soon enough, I'll be taking a look into particular applications. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically HTML is for drawing the page. The functionality of a web page must be programmed in some language like PHP, JavaScript...

To make it clear for you, here's a PHP hello world:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_syntax

And here there are some examples of data selection from a database:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Finnaly, I recommend you google about how to "summit a form" via PHP.

Good luck!

ps: If you find this answer helpful, don't forget to accept it! :P

Comment: Hey you're welcome, and despite some rough comments that you've got, you seem to be very organized and that's a key! You will get going with PHP and HTML forms in a month or less, it's relatively easy to use for filling and reading from databases. Keep it up!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. The comments made by others were also quite helpful, I just had to dig around myself as well.

Comment: that's the way the cookie crumbles haha